# CommandArguments not being passed to event handler in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, commandargument

This is a simple code, and not sure why `CommandArgument` is not being passed to my event handler.  Here is my aspx code:

```
</td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update Me"
    CommandName="Update Name" ComandArgument="First,Second,Third,Fourth"
    OnCommand = "Button1IsClicked" />
</td>
```

And here is my code behind:

```
       Protected Sub Button1IsClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs )

            Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
            Dim item As RepeaterItem = CType(btn.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)

            Dim CommandName As String = btn.CommandName            
            Dim MyArgs As String() = btn.CommandArgument.Split(",")
            Dim CommandArgument1 As String = MyArgs(0)
           ' and so on

    End Sub
```

Please note that my button is one of the Repeater Item.  I get the `CommandName` and `CommandText` fine, but MyArgs is always an empty string (`btn.CommandArgument` is always empty).  `CommandArgument` in btn and Repeater Item is a blank string.  I am expecting `"First,Second,Third,Fourth"` as its value.

I also tried with OnClick as event, but to no avail.
Any idea what may be going wrong?

Comment: FWIW, I just tested this with VS2013 using the Click event handler and it worked fine...

Answer (score 0):

`ComandArgument` is misspelled.  It needs to be `CommandArgument` in the following line:

`CommandName="Update Name" CommandArgument="First,Second,Third,Fourth"`

Comment: Did this address the issue?  If yes, then please mark it as the answer.  If not, please edit to update your code and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tony, that is perfect.  I was relying on MS intellisence to tell me that but no compilation error.  Thanks again.